# Two-Step Map-Reduce Multiplication in Spark (Java)

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-spark

I've read in a textfile of doubles and stored it into a JavaRDD, but am having difficulty implementing a two-step MapReduce matrix multiplication on it. Array is 50x50 and filled with random numbers from 1 to 100. I understand the underlying math but am unable to set up the matrix key pairs and multiply them properly.

Comment: Two step? Just map over the RDD to multiply. No reduce should be needed

Comment: There are several ways to implement the matrix multiplication in MapReduce, Depends on your preferences ( memory Vs. Communication). Is 50*50 is the only example data that you are going to do this implementation for?